# How can the Legion destroy Objects?

Tags: the-lost-room

In [*The Lost Room*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Room), Jennifer explains that the Legion exists to collect Objects - and destroy them so they won't bring further harm.

How is this possible? The Objects themselves are indestructible. (Except possibly within the Room, which I don't think the Legion could ever bank on...) Moreover, in the finale, the Occupant refers to a "Conservation of Objects" - saying that if an Object *is* destroyed, another one is created in its place.

Are the Legion a hopeless cause, or do they have some method of destroying/neutralizing Objects that wasn't made clear?

Comment: The one possibility that always seemed most likely to me required the key; get all of the objects, return them to the room, and close the door (with the Key inside.)  The objects would all be locked off from reality, with no way to get to them, and, in the room, they have no special properties.  The occupant, however, makes this a bit.. harder... But, possibly, gathering ALL of the objects may have it's own effect.

Answer (score 4):

They certainly wanted to destroy them, but it's clear that they have not figured out how to do that. And, as you suggest, it may even be impossible.

This is hardly unusual for an activist organization, I might point out.

There is the possibility that they had intended to lock the Objects away in some difficult-to-open vault, but this may have been a dangerous action in itself... Objects in close proximity can react violently to each other, risking nothing less than the destruction of the universe. While the experiment took place at the motel itself, this only required six Objects. There are over one hundred though, and if placed together even at vast distance from the motel, I don't think anything good could happen.

Answer (score 4):

No, they knew they couldn't destroy them, so they just wanted to get rid of them.  Make them inaccessible.  Hide them, bury them, shoot them into space, etc.  They wanted to make sure that nobody could ever get to Objects, so that the Objects couldn't destroy any more lives.